# Left Ctrl key not working in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, emacs

While running an OS in VirtualBox on Ubuntu 10.10 amd64, I find the <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>(left-ctrl) key is not being properly detected. (The <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>(right-ctrl) is used by Virtual Box, but the <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> key should be available.) This makes programs like `Emacs`, that heavily rely on the control key, not work correctly. Searching the Internet, I found similar complaints that were fixed in by turning off **Show position** of pointer when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed" in mouse preferences. Since this is already turned off on my system (actually in both host and client OS's), I don't think this is the problem.

My question: is this a bug, a feature or operator error?

Comment: This appears to have been fixed for 13.04 (Raring): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/9441

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround for Emacs in Virtual Box you can operate the control key functions by pressing

<kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd> then release <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> while holding <kbd>Control</kbd> and press the corresponding funktion key (e.g. <kbd>N</kbd>).

To make use of the right shift key (however that key is also not fully operational in Virtual Box) you can define another <kbd>Host</kbd> key from the Virtual Box Manager settings in *File -> Preferences -> Input*.

Comment: Yes, this works for me. Thanks! I can now do things like C-x C-f in Emacs.

Comment: I was trying to do something similar for uni as a purely academic exercise (i.e. reading the Emacs manual and trying to EXACTLY replicate what was there). In the end I swapped to a different terminal with [ctrl]+[alt]+[f6] (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34519/10337) and ran the non-graphical, default version of Emacs with `emacs -nw -q sample`. This is a pretty specific use case, but it negates some of the issues you're describing. DISLAIMER - I'm pretty sure tty6 has some special purpose, but this is my sandbox Ubuntu VirtualBox instance and I don't care if I wreck it.

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu 12.04, disabling the mouse pointer (System settings ► Mouse and Touchpad ► Show position of pointer when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed) does the trick.

Comment: He stated in the question that this option was already turned off.

Comment: Although, your answer didn't apply to the original poster, it did work on my Ubuntu, which is I think 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

I could get the control key to work by disabling "Highlight the pointer when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the mouse preferences. This was on Fedora with Gnome 3, so it might not help you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>(left-ctrl) was not functioning in the Guest OS  because I have previously configured <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> key in the HOST OS to highlight the location of the mouse once pressed.

Once reverting in the HOST OS the <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> in the Guest OS is "back to business" as usual.
 
So Simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve a problem with my `LCTRL` (inside a Ubuntu Virtual Box VM) by enabling the Virtual Box preference "Auto Capture Keyboard" (under "Input").  Hope that helps someone.