# CTRL button in nano not registering (Ubuntu Server 16.04 in Virtualbox)

Tags: server, virtualbox, shortcut-keys, 16.04, nano

I am running Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS guest OS in Virtualbox 5.0.8 under Ubuntu MATE 15.10 LTS host OS. I am setting up a little development LAMP server and I am editing apache configuration files. I used nano to edit and everything seemed to work with the keyboard. However trying to save and exit the file doesn't seem to be working.

All of nano's commands seem to use the format of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>"Button"</kbd>. NOTE: The HOST Control button is <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> and I am trying to use the <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> for commands.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> - is the command to exit the file. however pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> (in combination, that is holding <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> and pressing the <kbd>X</kbd> button) only outputs the letter `x` to the file as if i was just pressing it by itself.

My main issue now is that I can't even exit the file to try it with `vi` instead (since it doesn't use any <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>"Button"</kbd> for simple editing (`:wq` will work).

Any help with this issue would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/36292/left-ctrl-key-not-working-in-virtualbox

Comment: Sorry about that I tried a search but my qeury must not have been very clear.  Also there is alot of useful info on that page however none of them is the solution i found.  Holding the shift key activates the left ctrl key, haven't tried it with any shift+ctrl commands (which I'm sure will lead to a conflict).  So remapping the key is probably a better permanent solution however, in my situation I had already done alot of editing and needed to save and exit rather than restart the VM and lose all changes.  This solution works for that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>F2</kbd>. It's an alternate key for `^x` -- that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

[image: instructions displayed in terminal]

Answer (score 0):

Well Some playing around with different combinations of keys let me use <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> seemed to work just like pressing <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>. So my solution was add the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to the combination.

Answer (score 0):

Double tap <kbd>esc</kbd>, it works the same! Found out today from https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/ :

> You can hit Escape twice instead of holding down the Control key, if you have trouble doing that. There are also some commands that require use of the Meta key. On most keyboard layouts, Meta equates to the Alt button.

I haven't been able to find an equivalent for <kbd>alt</kbd>, however.